# Sample size determination for power law

Tags: normal-distribution, sample-size, skewness, power-law

I am looking for a method to estimate a mean when the underlying samples are drawn from a skewed distribution.

Concretely, I have a population $P$ whose pdf largely follows a power law, where only a minority of entities has a very large contribution to the pdf. Given a sample $x \sim P$ (whose minimal size I am looking to determine), I measure variable $s$ that approximately can be described by a normal distribution (also when weighted to account for characteristics in $P$). Is it in that case correct to use $n=\frac{4Z^{2}\sigma ^{2}}{W^{2}}$ as my minimal sample size to estimate the mean of variable $s$? Do I need to compute the [weighted standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Weighted_sample_variance) to account for skewness in $P$?